# Allocate an array of INT_MAX-1 elements with realloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, stack-overflow, realloc

In the program, I have created an array of structs. The length of an array will not exceed INT_MAX from <limits.h> in C.

```
int new_size(int size, int single_el) {                                                                                              
    if (size < INT_MAX/2) {                                                                                                         
        return 2*single_el + 2*size                                                                                                     
    } else {
        return INT_MAX - 1;                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                               
}
    

int current_size(int single_el, int ind) {                                                                                             
    return ind*single_el;                                                                                                 
}      
    
void reall(struct **instr, int* size, int ind, int single_el) {                                                                   
    int cur_s = current_size(single_el, ind);                                                                                      
    if ( cur_s >= (*size)) {                                                                                                        
        int sisi = new_size(*size, single_el);                                                                                  
        *size = sisi;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        printf("%d\n", sisi);                                                                                              
        struct* t = realloc(*instr, (size_t)*size);                                                                         
        if (t == NULL)
            printf("well done\n");                                                                                        
        else
            *instr = t;                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

When I reach `size = INT_MAX - 1;` realloc returns null. How can I handle this, if I have assumed, that INT_MAX is correct size? I understand, that realloc returns null in case of lack of the memory, but what to do, if for me size to be correct? Therefore: **how to dynamically allocate the array of INT_MAX size?**

Here are valgrind errors:

```
    ==31211== Invalid write of size 1                                                                                       
==31211==    at 0x10CAE1: machine (obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==  Address 0xa9c8a018 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,342,177,240 alloc'd                                    
==31211==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
==31211==    by 0x10BE14: reall (obejsc10.c:234)                                                                        
==31211==    by 0x10CB37: machine (obejsc10.c:358)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211== Invalid write of size 4                                                                                       
==31211==    at 0x10CAE4: machine (obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         ==31211==  Address 0xa9c8a01c is 4 bytes after a block of size 1,342,177,240 alloc'd                                    
==31211==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
==31211==    by 0x10BE14: reall (obejsc10.c:234)                                                                        
==31211==    by 0x10CB37: machine (obejsc10.c:358)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         

==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211== Invalid write of size 4                                                                                       
==31211==    at 0x10CAE7: machine (obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==  Address 0xa9c8a020 is 8 bytes after a block of size 1,342,177,240 alloc'd                                    
==31211==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
==31211==    by 0x10BE14: reall (obejsc10.c:234)                                                                        
==31211==    by 0x10CB37: machine (obejsc10.c:358)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211== Invalid write of size 4                                                                                       
==31211==    at 0x10CAEE: machine(obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==  Address 0xa9c8a024 is 12 bytes after a block of size 1,342,177,240 alloc'd                                   
==31211==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
==31211==    by 0x10BE14: reall (obejsc10.c:234)                                                                        
==31211==    by 0x10CB37: machine (obejsc10.c:358)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211== Invalid write of size 4                                                                                       
==31211==    at 0x10CAF5: machine (obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==  Address 0xa9c8a028 is 16 bytes after a block of size 1,342,177,240 alloc'd                                   
==31211==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
==31211==    by 0x10BE14: reall (obejsc10.c:234)                                                                        
==31211==    by 0x10CB37: machine (obejsc10.c:358)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game (obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211==                                                                                                               
==31211== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)                                                
==31211==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xA9C8B000                                                        
==31211==    at 0x10CAEE: machine (obejsc10.c:362)                                                                      
==31211==    by 0x10D441: game(obejsc10.c:481)                                                                    
==31211==    by 0x10D615: main (obejsc10.c:512)                                                                         
==31211==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack                                                          
==31211==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but                                                         
==31211==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the                                                           
==31211==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.                                                          
==31211==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.                                                     Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is lack of memory? (Also bearing in mind that operating system may have allocation size limits)

Comment: It may be helpful if you provided a [mre]. You are not showing with what arguments you are calling these functions, and it is also unclear why you need so much code to demonstrate the issue. Wouldn't a single call to `malloc` be sufficient? Or does your problem only occur with `realloc`?

Comment: Check `errno` to see why it failed. Also check your OS limits (on Unix) with `ulimit -a`. And what is the value of `INT_MAX`?

Comment: if you didn't already, build as 64-bit  (32-bit process will certainly limit allocation)

Comment: `if (size < INT_MAX/2) { return 2*single_el + 2*size` --> test risks overflow.  Perhaps `if (size <= INT_MAX/2 - 2*single_el)`

Comment: `ind*single_el` also risks `int` overflow.  codarmy, why does code use type `int` to determine allocation size?